# Mixed Strategies in Bayes Nash Equilibrium (Bayesian Battle of the Sexes). Shouldn't it depend on $p$?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bayesian-game

I have a question about calculating mixed strategies in a Bayes Nash Equilibrium in a simple 2-player bimatrix game. To demonstrate the issue, consider ``Bayesian Battle of the Sexes.'' Suppose P1 faces a P2 whose type is unknown with probability $p$. An example is below in which $p=.5$.

[image]

Here's what's surprising to me. If you calculate the mixing strategy for P1 by making sure that P2 is indifferent, you wind up with P1 mixing strategies **that don't depend at all on $p$**. This seems strange to me.

**If P2's type is more clear, shouldn't the optimal mixed strategy shift to anticipate this?**

End of question. Addendum: The game above apparently has two mixed strategy EQMs:

1. P1 mixes $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, P2 left mixes (0,1), P2 right ($\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3}$).
2. P1 mixes $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3})$, P2 left mixes ($\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3}$), P2 right (0,1).

Like I said, this doesn't seem to depend on $p$ (the probability of facing the first type).

**Also:** Shouldn't this game have an odd # of EQM? I thought this was a rule of thumb. I am contemplating the idea that there's a third equilibrium that mixes the two above.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
Given game also has one pure-strategy Nash equilibrium besides the two you mentioned: Row player plays $C$, Column player (left) plays $C$ and right plays $H$ i.e. $C,H$.

Also, when player 1 chooses a mixed strategy in order to make player 2 indifferent, that does not necessarily mean that player 1 is choosing optimally. It is only when player 2 makes player 1 indifferent, then the mixed strategy chosen by 1 becomes optimal. In fact as $p$ gets close to $1$ (not necessarily equals 1), given that player 2 (left) chooses $H$ and player 2 (right) chooses $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$, player 1 will not choose $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, since player 1 is no longer indifferent between $C$ and $H$. Playing $C$ will give row player a payoff of $\frac{20}{3}(1-p)$, while playing $H$ gives him $\frac{10p}{3}+\frac{5}{3}$ and these are only equal when $p=\frac{1}{2}$.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose player 1 chooses a mixed strategy such that the left type of player 2 is indifferent between C and H. There is a unique mixed strategy that does this. The same mixed strategy, however, does NOT make the right type of player 2 indifferent. Loosely speaking, this is simply because the preferences of the left type are exactly those of the right type switched around. Thus it is impossible for player 1 to make both types indifferent simultaneously. Therefore, the probability $p$ plays no role when choosing a strategy such that at least one of them is indifferent.

This also indicates why there are exactly two equilibria.